# Python notebook: Reading the note from a file

Tags: python

I am having trouble with one of my online coding exercises that I am trying to complete. The program does not read my note from the program as it should.

The exercise is simple, it wants me to add a code and then read it with time format and has other some menu options:

> The last exercise in this chapter adds a small feature to the other continuous exercise project, the notebook. In this exercise, add a feature which includes the date and time of the written note to the program. The program works as earlier, but saves data in the form `[note]:::[date and time]` meaning that there is a three-colon separator between the note and timestamp. The timestamp can be generated as follows:
>
> ```
> import time       
> time.strftime("%X %x")
> '19:01:34 01/03/09'
> ```
>
> This returns the date and time in a nice, compact string. When
> working correctly, the program prints the following:
>
> (1) Read the notebook.
>
> (2) Add note.
>
> (3) Empty the notebook.
>
> (4) Quit
>
> Please select one: 2.
>
> Write a new note: Play football.
>
> (1) Read the notebook.
>
> (2) Add note.
>
> (3) Empty the notebook.
>
> (4) Quit.
>
> Please select one: 1.
>
> Play football:::21:11:24 11/04/11.
>
> (1) Read the notebook.
>
> (2) Add note.
>
> (3) Empty the notebook.
>
> (4) Quit.
>
> Please select one: 4.
>
> Notebook shutting down, thank you.

```
import time
    try:
        f=open("notebook.txt","r")
    
except Exception:
    mf=open("notebook.txt","w")
mf="notebook.txt"    
promptForNumbers = True
while True:
    if promptForNumbers:
        print("(1) Read the notebook\n(2) Add note\n(3) Empty the notebook\n(4) Quit\n")
        selection=int(input("Please select one: "))

if selection==1:
    handle = open(mf,"r")
    filetext = handle.read()

    print(filetext)
    
elif selection==2:
    filetext=input("Write a new note: ")

    myfile= open(mf, "w")
    myfile.write(filetext)
    myfile.write(":::")
    myfile.write(time.strftime("%X %x"))

elif selection==3:
    readfile = open(mf,"w")
    readfile.close()
    print("Notes deleted.")
    
elif selection == 4:
   
    print("Notebook shutting down, thank you.")
    break
else:
    print("Incorrect selection")
```

Comment: What does it do instead of what it should do? I guess it gives an IndentationError for the second line?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you for your reply. It does not read the note.

Comment: What does not read which note from where?

Comment: The program just does not reads the notes when prompted by user when selecting option (1) Read the notebook. It just skips over and asks the menu again instead of reading the note saved in the notebook.

Comment: For example: Please select one: 1

(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Quit

Please select one: 4
Notebook shutting down, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the first glance, your file handling is wrong.

```
    try:
        f=open("notebook.txt","r")
    
except Exception:
    mf=open("notebook.txt","w")
```

This thing really confuses me about why it is there, as you never use f anywhere, do not close it and if it raises an error you are opening the file as `mf` but you immediately lose the reference to it as you assign a filename to `mf`.
You are opening the file multiple times, but rarely close it.
The preferred way of opening a file in Python is using context manager like so:

```
with open(mf, "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(filetext)
    myfile.write(":::")
    myfile.write(time.strftime("%X %x"))
```

This way when you exit the `with` block you are guaranteed to have your file closed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `myfile.close()` after you finish writing to the file.

Ideally you should be closing the file after you finish operating on it (so it would be good to close `handle`.

Also, this might be bad formatting, but if your larger `if` is outside of `while` then you have to remove `break` in `selection==4`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are opening the file multiple times and not closing it, which could cause problems. Use `with` to handle files instead, as this will close the file automatically at the end of the block. Use `try...except` block to test whether the file exists at the point where the user tries to access it, rather than doing this at the start of the program.

```
import time
# Remove these lines which open the file without closing it (were you testing whether the file exists?) 
#try:
#        f=open("notebook.txt","r")
#    
#except Exception:
#    mf=open("notebook.txt","w")
mf="notebook.txt"    
promptForNumbers = True
while True:
    if promptForNumbers:
        print("(1) Read the notebook\n(2) Add note\n(3) Empty the notebook\n(4) Quit\n")
        selection=int(input("Please select one: "))

    if selection==1:
        try:
            with open(mf) as f:
                print(filetext.read())
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("The notebook file was not found")
    elif selection==2:
        text = input("Write a new note: ")
        with open(mf, "w") as f:
            f.write(text)
            f.write(":::")
            f.write(time.strftime("%X %x"))
    elif selection==3:
        with open(mf, "w") as f:
            pass
        print("Notes deleted.")   
    elif selection == 4:
        print("Notebook shutting down, thank you.")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect selection")
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are not handling files the right way. They should not be opened at the start of the program and they have to be closed each time after use. Also, you need the `"a"` mode for appending. For starters, remove the try and except blocks, since they only cause problems and `mf` is overridden anyway.,
The next problem is the string argument that encodes the mode. If you want to read the file, you have to use `"r"`, if you want to write something, you need `"a"` (or `"r"`). So if you want to be able to do both, you have to open the file each time the user chose an option. Finally, you have to close the file when you don't need it at the moment and that can be easily done by the `with open([filename], [mode]) as file:` term that automatically handles opening, closing and Errors in a save and readable way.

So for example:

```
if selection==1:
    handle = open(mf,"r")
    filetext = handle.read()
    print(filetext)
```

should become:

```
if selection==1:
    with open(mf, "r") as file:
        filetext = file.read()
        print(filetext)
```

That should solve every problem that is caused by interaction with files. though the rest of the code is rough on the eyes too and could use some refactoring (and should not be included in a StackOverflow question. Please try to provide minimal examples of your problem or question). Using f-Srings might be a nice way to get the task done in an easy and readably way.

Answer (score -1):

change selection 1 to the following code. It Should work.

```
if selection==1:
    with open(mf, "r") as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:

print("""
(1) Read the notebook
(2) Add note
(3) Empty the notebook
(4) Quit   
  """)
choice = input("Please select one: ")
    

if choice == '1':
    file = open("notebook.txt")
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    if content:
        
        print(content)
    else:
        print("Notebook is empty.")

elif choice == '2':
    new_note = input("Write a new note: ")
    file = open("notebook.txt", "a")
    file.write(new_note + "\n")
    file.close()


elif choice == '3':
    file = open("notebook.txt", "w")
    file.write("")
    file.close()
    print("Notes deleted.")

elif choice == '4':
    print("Notebook shutting down, thank you.")
    break

else:
    print("Incorrect selection. Please choose again.")
```

Comment: Hi Gabriele Gargani, welcome to SO. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks